# Snow Leopards Desktop Icons keeps Resizing Repeatedly

Tags: mac, osx-snow-leopard, operating-systems

I'm using a new macbook 10.6.5. I've been using mac OS for years. However, the problem that I'm getting is that the desktop icons keep resizing repeatedly. It keeps going to the biggest size possible and its driving me crazy.

I've been resizing it back to medium size all the time. But when I start doing something at the finder it starts resizing by itself once again.

Is there a fix to this problem? Please help.

Comment: Is it possible you just use the pinch gesture on your trackpad?

Answer (score 2):

It might be possible that you are resizing it using the trackpad. Disable it under System Preferences -> Trackpad and see if that helps.